# Angular ui-router not calling child controller in nested routes

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have my routes set up as below. Its too frustrating that the view in `view.tab` is loaded but its controller isn't called. I tried without the paramaters, but it still doesn't work as expected. Does anyone have any idea on how to solve this?

```
    $stateProvider
    .state('index', {
        url: '/',
        templateUrl: viewsRoot + 'restaurants/index.htm',
        controller: 'RestaurantsCtrl'
    })
    .state('view', {
        url: '/view',
        controller: 'RestaurantsViewCtrl',
        templateUrl: viewsRoot + '/restaurants/view.htm'
    })
    .state('view.tab', {
        url: '/orders',
        // controller: 'OrdersIndexCtrl',
        controller: function ($scope) {
            alert('This does not run');
        },
        views: {
            "view": {
                templateUrl: viewsRoot + '/restaurants/orders.htm'
            }
        }
    });

$urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to declare the controller along side the template:

```
views: {
            "view": {
                templateUrl: viewsRoot + '/restaurants/orders.htm',
                controller: 'MyController' // (or a function, etc.)
        }
```

The [UI-Router wiki](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-Views#views-override-states-template-properties) sort of alludes to this:

> If you define a views object, your state's templateUrl, template and templateProvider will be ignored. So in the case that you need a parent layout of these views, you can define an abstract state that contains a template, and a child state under the layout state that contains the 'views' object.

Controllers are paired with a view. So if it ignores the "template" properties defined on the state, it seems to imply that it will ignore the controller too.

If you want all of your named views to share a controller, define an abstract parent state as the wiki suggests.